# add an effect dynamically over all controls in xamarin forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have developed an effect and i wanted to add this dynamically over all my controls. For example i wrote an effect for date pickers and i would like to add this effect over all my date pickers in the app.
I don't want to repeat this code for all my controls.

```
<Entry.Effects>
    <local:FocusEffect />
</Entry.Effects>
```

I've followed this article: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/effects/creating/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add your effect using attached property. Then you can use styles to add that attached property to all your date pickers.

More info at:

https://medium.com/@ysmoradi/how-to-add-xamarin-native-platform-effect-to-all-elements-9214cf6d7b8a

and

https://github.com/ysmoradi/XamarinEffectsArticle